# How To Horizontially Center a Div with auto-width

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I get something like this to have auto-width (to get bigger/smaller based on what's in it):

```
<div id="example"><div id="foo">BlahBlah</div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PvfFy/901/

I have tried various solutions, and none of them seem to work.

So how can I get #example to center with auto-width?

Comment: which block to do for the center?

Comment: You've `left: 0` as well as `right: 0`, so it will stretch and occupy the whole viewport. Remove that. Make it `left: 50%;` and use the `transform: translateX(-50%);` trick. Remove the margins as well, they are playing no role here. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/PvfFy/902/

Comment: Your markup shown does not show an illustration of the problem and that markup must be shown here, not a third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow. You don't display any CSS at all.

Comment: This what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/PvfFy/906/ This centers the inner div.

Comment: Thanks @Abhitalks and @connexo! You both have been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the width with percent.  `width:80%;`

Comment: The requirement is width to be set to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code and see if it's what you are looking for

```
#example
{
 min-width: 100vw;
 height: 20vh;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 color: #869194;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: blue;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 2vh
}

#foo {
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 margin: 1em auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PvfFy/909/

Answer (score 0):

```
#example {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```